# How can I make a dialog box in jQuery UI open and fill the whole browser window?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I use to create a dialog box:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.createCommonDialog = function () {
        this.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 875,
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
                    $("#update-message").html('');
                    $("#dialogForm").submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {

            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am open the dialog box with the following:

```
    var dialogDiv = $('#commonDialog');
    dialogDiv.dialog('option', 'title', action + ': ' + viewID)
    dialogDiv.dialog('open');
```

Can someone tell me how I could modify this code so that there's an option for opening the dialog box and having it so that it fills the browser screen?  Please note there's more to the code but I just included the important parts to do with opening the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createCommonDialog` plugin will take some work to be able to be used to both initialize dialog as well as be able to pass options with an open handler.

Passing the width and height as open options nstead of in main `create` allows for window resizes

You could create a separate open function something along the lines of:

```
$.fn.openCommonDialog=function(action, viewID){
    var openOpts={
        width: $(window).width()-10,
        height: $(window).height()-10,
        'title': action + ': ' + viewID
    }

    $(this).dialog('option', openOpts).dialog('open');

};

 $('#commonDialog').openCommonDialog('my action', 765);
```

Comment: This is incomplete, in that function you should be accounting for a resize.  People should insert `$(window).resize(function(){$(this).dialog('option', { width: $(window).width()-10,  height: $(window).height()-10,});});` at the end of the funtion.  Also personally, the size should be a var but that is personal preference :D

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC really depends on the UI and if it is expected to have users resize while a dialog is open. In many UI's using dialog the likelyhood is that user won't

Comment: yes it would be optional, but its poor practice IMHO to leave chances for UI breakage open like that.  I know it's a detail thing but that is our job, the details.  But yes 100% a person could do without and just have them reload the page if the users uses windows snap feature after loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
height: $(window).height(),
width: $(window).width(),
```

That will make the dialog the same size as the viewport. Is that what you mean by fill the browser screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
height: $(window).height(),
width: $(window).width(),
```

Might help this